# C - fread doesn't seem to be reading the data back into memory

Tags: c, structure, binaryfiles, fread

I have a problem and I'm not sure what is causing it because this book I'm reading doesn't really explain the fread feature to thoroughly and even after reading some of the posts on here I still can't figure out what's going on. I figure it has something to do with reading the structure back into memory

The problem is that when it restores the array it still prints out blank as though it weren't restored, but it claims that the entire 100 parts were restored. I only made 3 struct parts when I dumped it, could this be a problem?

The structure has this form

```
    #define MAX_PARTS 100

    struct part {
        int number;
        char name[NAME_LEN+1];
        int on_hand;
    } inventory[MAX_PARTS];
```

And here is the functions

```
    void dump(void)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        const char *inv = "inventory.dat";
        int chk;

        if ((fp = fopen(inv, "wb")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file \"%s\"\n", *inv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        chk = fwrite(inventory, sizeof(struct part), MAX_PARTS, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "End of file reached\n");
        } else if (ferror(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A write error occured\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File has Dumped %d of %d\n", chk, num_parts);
    }

    void restore(void)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        const char *inv = "inventory.dat";
        int chk;

        if ((fp = fopen(inv, "rb")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file \"%s\"\n", *inv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        chk = fread(inventory, sizeof(struct part), MAX_PARTS, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "End of file reached\n");
        } else if (ferror(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A read error occurred\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File has restored %d parts\n", chk);
    }
```

Rest of code:

```
    /* Maintains a parts database (array version) */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "readline.h"

    #define NAME_LEN 25
    #define MAX_PARTS 100

    struct part {
        int number;
        char name[NAME_LEN+1];
        int on_hand;
    } inventory[MAX_PARTS];

    int num_parts = 0; /* number of parts currently stored */

    void dump(void);
    void restore(void);
    int find_part(int number);
    void insert(void);
    void search(void);
    void update(void);
    void print(void);

    /**********************************************************
     * main: Prompts the user to enter an operation code,     *
     *       then calls a function to perform the requested   *
     *       action. Repeats until the user enters the        *
     *       command 'q'. Prints an error message if the user *
     *       enters an illegal code.                          *
     **********************************************************/
     int main(void)
     {
         char code;

         for (;;) {
            printf("Enter operation code: ");
            scanf(" %c", &code);
            while (getchar() != '\n')   /* skips to end of file */
                ;
            switch (code) {
                case 'd': dump();
                          break;
                case 'r': restore();
                          break;
                case 'i': insert();
                          break;
                case 's': search();
                          break;
                case 'u': update();
                          break;
                case 'p': print();
                          break;
                case 'q': return 0;
                default: printf("Illegal code\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
         }
     }

    void dump(void)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        const char *inv = "inventory.dat";
        int chk;

        if ((fp = fopen(inv, "wb")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file \"%s\"\n", *inv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        chk = fwrite(inventory, sizeof(struct part), MAX_PARTS, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "End of file reached\n");
        } else if (ferror(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A write error occured\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File has Dumped %d of %d\n", chk, num_parts);
    }

    void restore(void)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        const char *inv = "inventory.dat";
        int chk;

        if ((fp = fopen(inv, "rb")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file \"%s\"\n", *inv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        chk = fread(inventory, sizeof(struct part), MAX_PARTS, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "End of file reached\n");
        } else if (ferror(fp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A read error occurred\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File has restored %d parts\n", chk);
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * find_part: Looks up a part number in the inventory     *
     *            array. Returns the array index if the part  *
     *            number is found, otherwise, returns -1.     *
     **********************************************************/
    int find_part(int number)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < num_parts; i++)
            if (inventory[i].number == number)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * insert: Prompts the user for information about a new   *
     *         part and then inserts the part into the        *
     *         database. Prints an error message and returns  *
     *         prematurely if the part already exists or the  *
     *         database is full.                              *
     **********************************************************/
    void insert(void)
    {
        int part_number;

        if (num_parts == MAX_PARTS) {
            printf("Database is full; can't add more parts.\n");
            return;
        }

        printf("Enter part number: ");
        scanf("%d", &part_number);

        if (find_part(part_number) >= 0) {
            printf("Part already exists.\n");
            return;
        }

        inventory[num_parts].number = part_number;
        printf("Enter part name: ");
        read_line(inventory[num_parts].name, NAME_LEN);
        printf("Enter quantity on hand: ");
        scanf("%d", &inventory[num_parts].on_hand);
        num_parts++;
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * search: Prompts the user to enter a part number, then  *
     *         looks up the part in the database. If the part *
     *         exists, prints the name and quantity on hand;  *
     *         if not, prints an error message.               *
     **********************************************************/
    void search(void)
    {
        int i, number;

        printf("Enter part number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        i = find_part(number);
        if (i >= 0) {
            printf("Part name: %s\n", inventory[i].name);
            printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", inventory[i].on_hand);
        } else
            printf("Part not found.\n");
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * update: Prompts the user to enter a part number.       *
     *         Prints an error message if the part doesn't    *
     *         exist; otherwise, prompts the user to enter    *
     *         change in quantity on hand and updates the     *
     *         database.                                      *
     **********************************************************/
    void update(void)
    {
        int i, number, change;

        printf("Enter part number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        i = find_part(number);
        if (i >= 0) {
            printf("Enter change in quantity on hand: ");
            scanf("%d", &change);
            inventory[i].on_hand += change;
        } else
            printf("Part not found.\n");
    }

    /**********************************************************
     * print: Prints a listing of all parts in the database,  *
     *        showing the part number, part name, and         *
     *        quantity on hand. Parts are printed in the      *
     *        order in which they were entered into the       *
     *        database.                                       *
     **********************************************************/
    void print(void)
    {
        int i;

        printf("Part Number   Part Name                "
               "Quantity on Hand\n");
        for (i = 0; i < num_parts; i++)
            printf("%7d       %-25s%11d\n", inventory[i].number,
                   inventory[i].name, inventory[i].on_hand);
    }
```

Comment: You have not pasted enough code for us to replicate the problem. The bug is likely in code not shown.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I added the rest of the code...Not sure how that would help but thanks for the help

Comment: It helps because that's where the bug was. See my answer.

Comment: It's really easy to get stuck in the details and miss something that's absurdly obvious once someone points it out to you. Often, taking a break from the code and then coming back to it fresh helps. But definitely get in the habit of adding lots of `printf` statements to code to narrow down the issue. (Or learn to use a good debugger.)

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that @DavidSchwartz do you have any recommendations? I use Code::Blocks because when I first started I was having trouble figuring out how to get Eclipse setup. I got Python setup on it but I haven't tried setting it up for C again since I first started learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic attempts at debugging would have revealed the error. Just adding logging to the `print` function would have made the problem obvious.

When you restore, you don't change `num_parts`. So when you ask it to print, it prints zero parts. If `num_parts` is part of the data your program needs, then it too needs to be saved/restored. Alternatively, write out only the number of parts that are populated and set `num_parts` in your restore function to the number of parts read.

Comment: LOL hahaha I feel like a complete idiot, sorry for even bothering you guys over this...I just felt as though this book rushed through reading and writing to files and so I thought I was somehow was overlooking something to do with fwrite or fread.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote `MAX_PARTS`, it will read those many records. So `chk` will be `MAX_PARTS`.

It will give you whatever you wrote. If you wrote valid 3 records, then it should read 3 valid records, others will be garbage.

Comment: Alright I made that change, it now writes only the number of parts currently stored and it restores the same number of parts....but when I choose 'p' for print it still prints a blank part list